# Block website in Adobe Cloud

Tags: magento2, multi-website, magento2-cloud

I have a Magento website into Adobe Cloud.
There are many websites and each website has own domain.
I need to block access to a website/domain except from some IP addresses.
Do you know how to do?
Thank you,
Paul

Comment: Did you try fastly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Adobe Cloud Project UI has the ability to add HTTP access control, as far as I know, it cannot do domain/website specific restrictions.

However, I'm certain you can do this by using **Fastly VCL custom snippets.**
https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/cdn/cloud-vcl-custom-snippets.html

You can add them using

- Adobe Commerce admin panel using Fastly store configurations
- Using Fastly APIs

For example, the following VCL snippet might help you achieve this.  (haven't tested in a real project, please test)

```
# Your custom VCL Snippet should render a VCL like this
# the ACL name is office_ip_ranges.

acl office_ip_ranges {
  "192.0.2.0"/24;                              # internal office
  "198.51.100.4";                              # remote VPN office
  "2001:db8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff";    # ipv6 address remote
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # block all requests to yourdomain website from IP addresses not in office_ip_ranges
  if (req.origin_host ~ "^yourdomain" && ! (client.ip ~ office_ip_ranges)) {
    error 403 "Forbidden";
  }
}
```